# Como carregar varias paginas .html com ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Eu estou usando esse codigo para carregar um pagina .html, porem ele não cria varias como eu gostaria, tenho a sensação que ele só consegue criar ela uma vez.
Eu gostaria de criar varias delas.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        $.post('linha.html', function (html) 
        {
            $('#baseTorrent').html(html);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Não entendi o que quer fazer. Esse código busca o mesmo html 4 vezes e coloca no mesmo lugar! O loop não faz sentido...

Comment: @bfavaretto Mas ele cria 4 htmls distintos ou ele apaga o ultimo criado e cria um novo ??

Comment: Apaga e recria. Você substitui 4x o conteúdo de #baseTorrent

Comment: Talvez você esteja querendo $('#baseTorrent').append(html)

Comment: Perfeito, poderia colocar isso como resposta por favor ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta linha substitui todo o conteúdo de `#baseTorrent` pelo que tiver sido passado:

```
$('#baseTorrent').html(html);
```

Pelo que você diz, você quer acrescentar mais conteúdo, não substituir. Para isso, use [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

```
$('#baseTorrent').append(html);
```

Com essa mudança, você terá esse HTML repetido 4 vezes dentro de `#baseTorrent`.

Outra coisa, se é mesmo pra repetir o HTML, você não precisa ir buscá-lo quatro vezes no servidor. Melhor fazer assim:

```
$.post('linha.html', function (html) 
{
    for(var i=0; i<4; i++) {
        $('#baseTorrent').append(html);
    }
});
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Lucas, veja meu complemento

Comment: Obrigado pela dica no complemento :D